# How do I use a string as a parameter

Tags: autohotkey

very new to autohotkey. Im struggling to find how do I use a string as a variable for ImageSearch. In my code I want to search for image1.png and image2.png using only one fuction, where I send the name of the image through parameter.

```
z:: 
    imageSearchFunction("image1.png")
    imageSearchFunction("image2.png")
return

imageSearchFunction(imagePath)
    ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, ScreenStartX, ScreenStartY, ScreenEndX, ScreenEndY, imagePath
    if (ErrorLevel = 2)
                MsgBox Error2
            else if (ErrorLevel = 1)
                MsgBox Error1
            else
                MsgBox Found the image
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try wrapping the last parameter in %'s (legacy variable declaration) `ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, ScreenStartX, ScreenStartY, ScreenEndX, ScreenEndY, %imagePath%`. Also make sure the images are in the working directory.  If not, try passing in the full path. Also, you might get additional info on the exact error using a Try-Catch set up. Let us know . . .

Answer (score 0):

A lot wrong with this, lets start off with the code with which I guess was supposed to create a [function](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Functions.htm).
To create a function you need to follow this syntax

```
function(param1, param2, ...)
{

}
```

Then your other problem is referring to variables in the legacy syntax.
So, you're using a command. Every command uses legacy syntax in every parameter (unless otherwise specified in the documentation).
When you just type in `ScreenStartX, ScreenStartY, ScreenEndX, ScreenEndY, imagePath`, it's interpreted as literal text. You're going to want to tell AHK to evaluate an expression on those parameters and then you can refer to the variable just by typing its name.
To do that, you start off the parameters with a `%` followed up by a whitespace.
`% ScreenStartX, % ScreenStartY, % ScreenEndX, % ScreenEndY, % imagePath`

Then you also have the problem of the variables `ScreenStartX`, `ScreenStartY`, `ScreenEndX` and `ScreenEndY` never even being defined. At least not in the code you provided and certainly not in the function's scope.
I'll just slap them some random values, since I have no idea what you're actually going for.

```
z:: 
    imageSearchFunction("image1.png")
    imageSearchFunction("image2.png")
return

imageSearchFunction(imagePath)
{
    ;should be made static, but I wont
    ;confuse you with that, since this more 
    ;than likely isnt the desired usage anyway
    ScreenStartX := 0
    ScreenStartY := 0
    ScreenEndX := 700
    ScreenEndY := 500
    
    ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, % ScreenStartX, % ScreenStartY, % ScreenEndX, % ScreenEndY, % imagePath
    if (ErrorLevel = 2)
        MsgBox, % "Error2"
    else if (ErrorLevel = 1)
        MsgBox, % "Error1"
    else
        MsgBox, % "Found the image at X: " FoundX ", Y: " FoundY
}
```

Comment: I copied your code but change ImageSearch line into     ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, ScreenStartX, ScreenStartY, ScreenEndX, ScreenEndY, % imagePath. Basically removed % infront of everything but imagePath. It worked, Im curiuos why. Anyways Thanks a lot, im real new to ahk as you can see

Comment: If it works despite you defining non existent variables, I'd suspect it defaults to searching from the whole screen. Just a guess though, the documentation doesn't seem to mention this, and I cba go check what actually happens myself. But anyway, what are those variables supposed to be? I could let u know the proper way to do it.